# Print Every Code Golf tag

Tags: code-golf, internet

*Huge omega thanks to @wasif for emailing me this challenge idea in its basic form*

Everyone knows that questions on StackExchange require tags - labels that allow posts to be grouped together by category. However, most of the time, I barely know which tags exist, because there's just *so many* of them.
Henceforth, today's task is to tell me every single tag that exists on the Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange.

### The Challenge

Write a program or function that prints/returns a list of all available tags on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com
As tags can be created/deleted at any time, simply hard-coding a list of tags is not a valid solution - the list must be correct at run-time regardless of when the program/function is executed.
The tags avaliable can be seen [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags)

### Rules

- As this is an [internet](/questions/tagged/internet) challenge, internet connections are allowed. However, web requests can only be made to codegolf.stackexchange.com and api.stackexchange.com domains.
- Output can be given in any convenient and reasonable format.
- The tags can be in any order, so long as all current tags are returned.
- The exact name of the tags must be used (e.g. `code-golf` is valid, `code GOLF` is not valid.)
- And as usual, standard loopholes apply, shortest code wins

### Example Program

```python
import urllib.request
import regex

pobj = regex.compile('rel="tag">(.*)</a>')
page_number = 2
req = urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags?page=1&tab=name")
data = req.read().decode('utf-8')
tags = []
while data.count("tag") != 43:
    tags += pobj.findall(data)
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags?page={page_number}&tab=name")
    data = req.read().decode('utf-8')
    page_number += 1
    
print(tags)
```

Comment: Can we assume amount of tags stable enough? so we can hardcode page amount

Comment: @l4m2 the program has to output every tag at time of execution, so hard coding probably isn't a valid option

Comment: But it's unlikely that there's at some time lot more tags or lot less tags

Comment: I'm still going to say no in this case. Answers should work regardless of tag count

Comment: Do we assume infinite quota_remaining, then?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that

Comment: Oh I just read these comments.  My answer assumes >=3000 tags.  Currently there are >300.  Is this ok?

Comment: I must be getting old - what is the significance of *omega* in *Huge omega thanks*?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Maybe it's like "mega" but it's "omega"?

Comment: Omega here is indeed a play on "mega", but also a tribute to Omega Flowey. @Makonede

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>60</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```
[N>’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/›´?€¼=ƒËŠˆ&€®=ÿ’.wD2è'eQ#“e":"“¡¦ε'"¡н]\)
```

Outputs as a list of pages, where each page is a list of tags.

```
[N>’...’.wD2è'eQ#“e":"“¡¦ε'"¡н]\)  # trimmed program
[               #                  # while...
            è                      # character in...
        .wD                        # data of response from URL...
                                   # (implicit) "http://" concatenated with...
   ’...’                           # "api.stackexchange.com/tags?site=codegolf&page=ÿ"...
                                   # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
 N                                 # current index in loop...
  >                                # plus 1...
            è                      # at index...
           2                       # literal...
                #                  # is not...
               Q                   # equal to...
             'e                    # literal...
        .w                         # push data of response from URL...
                                   # (implicit) "http://" concatenated with...
   ’...’                           # "api.stackexchange.com/tags?site=codegolf&page=ÿ"...
                                   # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
 N                                 # current index in loop...
  >                                # plus 1...
                       ¡           # split by...
                 “e":"“            # literal...
                        ¦          # excluding the first...
                         ε         # with each element replaced by...
                             н     # first element of...
                                   # (implicit) current element in map...
                            ¡      # split by...
                          '"       # literal
                              ]    # exit map
                              ]    # exit infinite loop
                               \   # delete top element of stack
                                )  # push stack
                                   # implicit output
```

Comment: I was about to suggest using dictionary compression and then realised I was being a stupid idiot because I was looking at the unpacked strings in the explanation. Very well done!

Comment: @Lyxal Thanks! I also just checked the source code and turns out that 05AB1E does in fact implicitly add `http://` if it's not present, saving me three bytes. :)

Comment: See the Jyxal answer, which beats this by 12 bytes.

Comment: See my comment on it.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jyxal 0.2.0](https://github.com/Vyxal/Jyxal/tree/0.2.0), 44 bytes

```
0{›:`ȯø.⟩β•∵.•⅛/ɾƈ?λ→=%&λẋ=¬⋎»₅`%¨UøJht(ntt,
```

[Jyxal-is-not-hosted-anywhere-so-read-the-readme-to-see-how-to-try-this](https://github.com/Vyxal/Jyxal/blob/master/README.md)

Fixed thanks to @emanresu A

Absolutely crushes 05AB1E. On my machine, it goes through the first 25 pages before getting a 403 and printing `4` forever. Unfortunately, Vyxal cannot decompress zipped responses so I kinda had to use Jyxal in place. This is heavily dependent on the ordering of the values in the JSON response.

```
0{›:`ȯø.⟩β•∵.•⅛/ɾƈ?λ→=%&λẋ=¬⋎»₅`%¨UøJht(ntt, # I don't need the 2 closing parens at the end.
0                                            # Push 0 (Jyxal does not have implicit input yet)
 {                                           # Loop forever
  ›                                          # And increment the number
                                %            # Replace all "%" in the string...
    `ȯø.⟩β•∵.•⅛/ɾƈ?λ→=%&λẋ=¬⋎»₅`             # "api.stackexchange.com/tags?page=%&site=codegolf"
   :                                         # With the current loop index
                                 ¨U          # Make a GET request to that URL...
                                   øJ        # And decode the JSON response
                                     h       # Get the first key-value pair...
                                      t      # And the second item; that is, the "items" array
                                       (n    # For each item in that array...
                                         t   # Get the last key-value pair and then...
                                          t  # Get the value
                                           , # Print that value
```

Comment: Nice! If you've implemented `₄` (26) yet you can save a byte with that. And if you've implemented `ƛ` (map) yet you can save a couple more bytes with that by removing the `n`.

Comment: I'm still in the lead, as yours assumes there are no more than 25 pages while mine works no matter how many.

Comment: @Makonede (to seggan) replacing `25(n` with `{›:` will make it work no matter how many.

Comment: @Makonede now I'm in the lead ;) Thanks emanresu A

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3 + `requests`, 143 bytes

```
from requests import*
p=1
while[print(x["name"])for x in get(f"http://api.stackexchange.com/tags?page={p}&site=codegolf").json()["items"]]:p+=1
```

-19 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan
-5 bytes thanks to dingledooper

Comment: Would `while a:a=[print(x["name"])for...];p+=1` work? ...Edit: or even `while[print(x["name"])for...]:p+=1`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yep, looks like it does! Thanks!

Comment: -2 by using `"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?site=codegolf&page="+p` instead of `f"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?page={p}&site=codegolf"`.

Comment: @Makonede you can't add strings and integers in python

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I knew that, just forgot that `p` was an int

Comment: `https://api.stackexchange.com/tags?page={p}&site=codegolf` without the version seems to work, no? (Edit: I think you can also drop the `s` from `https`.

Comment: @dingledooper Looks like it, should've thought to try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (Firefox chrome), 135 bytes

```javascript
f=async(i=1)=>(await((await fetch('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags?page='+i)).text())).match(/[\w-]+(?=&#3)/g).map(alert)|f(i+1)
```

1. <del>Open [Browser Console of Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console);</del> You may however open console on this page instead;
2. Paste codes there;
3. Invoke it by running `f()`;
4. Click to close many many `alert`'s

---

Source codes for tags page contains line

```html
<a href="/questions/tagged/code-golf" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;code-golf&#39;" rel="tag">code-golf</a>
```

We match the text `code-golf` between `&#39;` by `/[\w-]+(?=&#3)/g`.

The recursion terminate when ith page contains no tags. While the match result is null, and `.map` on `null` cause an error.

Comment: Would that work on `Run Snippet`?

Comment: @l4m2 As long as you have permission to access that domain. Either by executing on same origin or as chrome code.

Comment: I mean if so you'd make a `run` in your post?

Comment: @l4m2 The code snippets in SE sites run under  a different domain as I know

Comment: `f=async i=>(await((await fetch('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags?page='+-~i)).text())).match(/[\w-]+(?=&#3)/g).map(alert)|f(-~i)`?

Comment: `f=i=>fetch('http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags?page='+-~i).then(_=>_.text().then(_=>_.match(/[\w-]+(?=&#3)/g).map(alert)|f(-~i)))`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 176 bytes

```js
async _=>{t=[];i=1;do t.push(...(j=await (await fetch("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?site=codegolf&page="+i++)).json()).items);while(j.has_more)return t.map(d=>d.name)}
```

Must be run on `api.stackexchange.com` subdomain; I use `/docs` for testing.

Comment: If you're going to run it on the `api.stackexchange.com` domain, why don't you use a relative path?

Comment: @Neil Something like [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12271/)? storing info in URL bar should be disallowed

Comment: @l4m2 Program already only works on the `api.stackexchange.com` domain, so I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @Neil It also runs on, for example, `api.stackexchange.com/docs`. Either way I think it'd be kind of cheaty to use a relative path anyway.

Comment: Well, it only needs to be relative from `http://api.stackexchange.com` (because you don't know which page you're on) but that still saves 28 bytes...

Comment: @Neil I still think it's cheating. The only reason it has to run on that domain is CORS protection; if that didn't exist it should still be able to work from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + wget + jq, 86

Assumes there are no more than 99 pages of results (currently 10 pages).

```bash
wget -qO- api.stackexchange.com/tags?site=codegolf\&page={1..99}|zcat|jq .items[].name
```

Testing this blew through my daily API requests limit pretty quick.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to connect to share you're answer.